# Fedora17: yum update not working

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, yum, fedora-17

I am new to linux environment and I have been assigned the task of installing a browser in my system (which I feel a really tough work in linux as a first time user).

When I am trying to run the command: yum update then I am getting the below error:

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# yum update
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/17/Everything/i386/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found : http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/17/Everything/i386/os/repodata/repomd.xml
Trying other mirror.
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/17/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found : http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/17/i386/repodata/repomd.xml
Trying other mirror.
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/17/Everything/i386/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found : http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/17/Everything/i386/os/repodata/repomd.xml
```

Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from fedora: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

Please let me know how to resolve this. I am struggling with this from a long time.

Comment: Fedora 17 is wayyyy too old and already past end-of-life.  The update repositories for F17 are likely defunct.  Please install Fedora 20, a supported version, and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved by changing the baseurl in the fedora.repo and fedora-updates.repo files present in the /etc/yum.repos.d folder.

This is needed since Fedora 17 has already past end-of-life.